# Creating a list of temporary files for each string in a list?

Tags: c#, automated-tests

I'm trying to write an automated test and as part of the set up, what I ideally want to do it create a list of temporary files to be used later in the test (rather than having a folder full of lots of blank files clogging up my solution).

As it stands my test setup looks like this:

```
var fileNames = new List<string>
            {
                "file1.doc",
                "file2.doc",
                "file3.doc",
                "file4.doc",
                "file5.doc",
                "file6.doc
            };


foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    .......
}
```

I've tried look at "new Stream..." but i'm not 100% sure that's what i'm actually after.

Any ideas??

Comment: [`File.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: OH! For the "path" that it requires would i just pass in "fileName"?

Comment: Then the file will be created in the working directory of the process (in your case the test runner process). It may be better to provide a full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`File.Create()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_Create_System_String_) to create the files:

```
fileNames.ForEach(f => File.Create(f).Close()); // don't forget to close the file again
```